# aws - how to set aws editor font-size globally?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Despite the fact that I see 'project' and 'user' settings

[image]

these both turn out to be specific to each lambda function.

Is there any way I can make the editor have different settings (the most obvious one being a larger font for older eyes) that apply to ALL lambdas that I open in the aws editor

Comment: Mmm, I couldn't see a way to make the Font Size stick for all functions, either. You could use Zoom in the browser, but it makes _all_ elements of the page bigger, not just the editor.

Comment: Yeah, although if u have clicked into the text itself, just the text panel zooms in which is quite handy, but again, u have to do it every time for every editing session for every function.

Answer (score 1):

I opened a case for aws support team about this issue since I'm suffering from it as well, this is there answer:

> Hi,
>
> I am contacting you for your case about Lambda font size.
>
> I understand you want to have the same font size for all your existing
>   and future Lambda functions without change the settings every time.
>   Based on my investigation, this functionality appears to not be
>   available in the Lambda console and the settings do not seem to
>   persist as one would expect.  I am going to submit a bug/feature
>   request to the Lambda service team on your behalf to hopefully address
>   this for the future.
>
> In the meantime, the code editor in Lambda console is supported by
>   Cloud9. So, if desired you can set up a Cloud9 environment and import
>   your Lambda functions. You can also create new lambda functions there.
>   In this environment all the lambda functions will have the same font
>   size settings which will solve your problem. Please refer to [this
>   link for detailed instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/lambda-functions.html).
>
> The other option would be to use the AWS SAM CLI and IDE toolkit or
>   other local editor. With this toolkit installed, you can edit and test
>   your Lambda function locally without the cost overhead of Cloud9.
>   Please see this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-install.html) if you want to install it.